# Can't change SPN addresses for SuccessFactors gallery app in Azure

Tags: azure, office365, sap-successfactors

Prehistory is the following:

We use cloud SAP SuccessFactors app. We publish it for our users via Azure enterprise apps with SAML SSO configured with SAP support. And till last week everything worked good.

But this week we faced with the problem. SSO stopped working and started to redirect to old test link. We used SAML debugger add-in in chrome and we see this wrong redirection.

I struggled with Azure PowerShell and finally found that old link among others in SPN addresses list.

I used this command

```
(Get-MsolServicePrincipal -ObjectId "_our app objectid_").Addresses
```

BUT

I can not correct this list. If I try to create an array of such objects and then

```
Set-MsolServicePrincipal - Addresses $array
```

I get an `invalid syntax error`.

Maybe some PowerShell guru is watching and can guide or paste some idea I would be so much appreciated.

MS support in India says NO. Impossible to change Addresses for gallery apps.
SAP support say just delete this app and create from scratch.

Comment: `Set-MsolServicePrincipal - Addresses $array` you have an extra space there. Maybe `Set-MsolServicePrincipal -Addresses $array` would work?

Comment: Nono. It's not space. My copy paste mistmatch. It something in azure. If i simply use $arr=(Get-msol blabla).adresses and then at once set-msol blabla -addresses $arr then i get an error that it's impossible to convert simple stribg object to azure.object. So i've created an array of such objects like this $array= @() and then $object = new-object -type azure.object and then took values from spn addresses to this array of azure objects like $object = (get-msol blabla).addresses[0] then $array += $object an so on for all elements of array

Comment: Recreated from scratch